# Using ServerManager to list virtual directories separated by type

Tags: c#, iis, c#-4.0, configuration, iis-7

I'm using ServerManager (Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll) to create an Application to manage my web servers, All of my server are running IIS 7 and above. Majority of the site is complete, i can manage servers, sites, FTP, SSL etc.

Here is my issue,
I am able to create virtual directories and applications, but having an issue with listing them separately when viewing the site information as you can do in IIS. I am able to list the all together as Virtual Directories by just getting `item.VirtualDirectories[0].PhysicalPath` but would like to show Applications in one column and basic virtual directories in the second column. I'm sure i need to be looking for if root application path is siteid, or if it has an AppPool somehow but having a hard time figuring how. Any help would be appreciated.
My Code:

SiteVirtualDirectory.cs

```
private string anonymousUsername;
    private string anonymousUserPassword;
    private string contentPath;
    private bool enableWritePermissions;
    private bool enableParentPaths;
    private bool enableDirectoryBrowsing;
    private bool enableAnonymousAccess;
    private bool enableWindowsAuthentication;
    private bool enableBasicAuthentication;
    private bool enableDynamicCompression;
    private bool enableStaticCompression;
    private string defaultDocs;
    private string httpRedirect;
    private HttpError[] httpErrors;
    private HttpErrorsMode errorMode;
    private HttpErrorsExistingResponse existingResponse;
    private MimeMap[] mimeMaps; 
    private HttpHeader[] httpHeaders;
    private bool aspInstalled;
    private string aspNetInstalled;
    private string phpInstalled;
    private bool perlInstalled;
    private bool pythonInstalled;
    private bool coldfusionInstalled;
    private bool cgiBinInstalled;
    private string applicationPool;
    private bool dedicatedApplicationPool;
    private string parentSiteName;
    private bool redirectExactUrl;
    private bool redirectDirectoryBelow;
    private bool redirectPermanent;
    private bool sharePointInstalled;
    private bool iis7;
    private string consoleUrl;
    private string php5VersionsInstalled;

    public string AnonymousUsername
    {
        get { return anonymousUsername; }
        set { anonymousUsername = value; }
    }

    public string AnonymousUserPassword
    {
        get { return anonymousUserPassword; }
        set { anonymousUserPassword = value; }
    }

    public string ContentPath
    {
        get { return contentPath; }
        set { contentPath = value; }
    }

    public string HttpRedirect
    {
        get { return httpRedirect; }
        set { httpRedirect = value; }
    }

    public string DefaultDocs
    {
        get { return defaultDocs; }
        set { defaultDocs = value; }
    }

    public MimeMap[] MimeMaps
    {
        get { return mimeMaps; }
        set { mimeMaps = value; }
    }

    public HttpError[] HttpErrors
    {
        get { return httpErrors; }
        set { httpErrors = value; }
    }

    public HttpErrorsMode ErrorMode
    {
        get { return errorMode; }
        set { errorMode = value; }
    }

    public HttpErrorsExistingResponse ExistingResponse
    {
        get { return existingResponse; }
        set { existingResponse = value; }
    }

    public string ApplicationPool
    {
        get { return this.applicationPool; }
        set { this.applicationPool = value; }
    }

    public bool EnableParentPaths
    {
        get { return this.enableParentPaths; }
        set { this.enableParentPaths = value; }
    }

    public HttpHeader[] HttpHeaders
    {
        get { return this.httpHeaders; }
        set { this.httpHeaders = value; }
    }

    public bool EnableWritePermissions
    {
        get { return this.enableWritePermissions; }
        set { this.enableWritePermissions = value; }
    }

    public bool EnableDirectoryBrowsing
    {
        get { return this.enableDirectoryBrowsing; }
        set { this.enableDirectoryBrowsing = value; }
    }

    public bool EnableAnonymousAccess
    {
        get { return this.enableAnonymousAccess; }
        set { this.enableAnonymousAccess = value; }
    }

    public bool EnableWindowsAuthentication
    {
        get { return this.enableWindowsAuthentication; }
        set { this.enableWindowsAuthentication = value; }
    }

    public bool EnableBasicAuthentication
    {
        get { return this.enableBasicAuthentication; }
        set { this.enableBasicAuthentication = value; }
    }

    public bool EnableDynamicCompression
    {
        get { return this.enableDynamicCompression; }
        set { this.enableDynamicCompression = value; }
    }
    public bool EnableStaticCompression
    {
        get { return this.enableStaticCompression; }
        set { this.enableStaticCompression = value; }
    }

    public bool AspInstalled
    {
        get { return this.aspInstalled; }
        set { this.aspInstalled = value; }
    }

    public string AspNetInstalled
    {
        get { return this.aspNetInstalled; }
        set { this.aspNetInstalled = value; }
    }

    public string PhpInstalled
    {
        get { return this.phpInstalled; }
        set { this.phpInstalled = value; }
    }

    public bool PerlInstalled
    {
        get { return this.perlInstalled; }
        set { this.perlInstalled = value; }
    }

    public bool PythonInstalled
    {
        get { return this.pythonInstalled; }
        set { this.pythonInstalled = value; }
    }

    public bool ColdFusionInstalled
    {
        get { return this.coldfusionInstalled; }
        set { this.coldfusionInstalled = value; }
    }

    public bool DedicatedApplicationPool
    {
        get { return this.dedicatedApplicationPool; }
        set { this.dedicatedApplicationPool = value; }
    }

    public string ParentSiteName
    {
        get { return this.parentSiteName; }
        set { this.parentSiteName = value; }
    }

    public bool RedirectExactUrl
    {
        get { return this.redirectExactUrl; }
        set { this.redirectExactUrl = value; }
    }

    public bool RedirectDirectoryBelow
    {
        get { return this.redirectDirectoryBelow; }
        set { this.redirectDirectoryBelow = value; }
    }

    public bool RedirectPermanent
    {
        get { return this.redirectPermanent; }
        set { this.redirectPermanent = value; }
    }

    public bool CgiBinInstalled
    {
        get { return this.cgiBinInstalled; }
        set { this.cgiBinInstalled = value; }
    }

    public bool SharePointInstalled
    {
        get { return this.sharePointInstalled; }
        set { this.sharePointInstalled = value; }
    }

    public bool IIs7
    {
        get { return this.iis7; }
        set { this.iis7 = value; }
    }

    public string ConsoleUrl
    {
        get { return consoleUrl; }
        set { consoleUrl = value; }
    }

    public string Php5VersionsInstalled
    {
        get { return php5VersionsInstalled; }
        set { php5VersionsInstalled = value; }
    }
[XmlIgnore]
        public string VirtualPath
        {
            get
            {
                // virtual path is rooted
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ParentSiteName))
                    return "/"; //
                else if (!Name.StartsWith("/"))
                    return "/" + Name;
                //
                return Name;
            }
        }
[XmlIgnore]
        public string FullQualifiedPath
        {
            get
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ParentSiteName))
                    return Name;
                else if (Name.StartsWith("/"))
                    return ParentSiteName + Name;
                else
                    return ParentSiteName + "/" + Name;
            }
        }
```

Get Virtual Directories:

```
public class GetVirtualDirectories(ServerManager iismanager, string siteId)
        {
            if (!SiteExists(iismanager, siteId))
                return new SiteVirtualDirectory[] { };

            var vdirs = new List<SiteVirtualDirectory>();
            var iisObject = iismanager.Sites[siteId];
            //
            foreach (var item in iisObject.Applications)
            {
                // do not list root Virtual Directory
                if (item.Path == "/")
                    continue;
                //
                vdirs.Add(new SiteVirtualDirectory
                {
                    Name = ConfigurationUtility.GetNonQualifiedVirtualPath(item.Path),
                    ContentPath = item.VirtualDirectories[0].PhysicalPath
                });
            }
            //
            return vdirs.ToArray();
        }
```

Comment: It is interesting that every site has its root application, and every application has its root virtual directory. So your logic should carefully treat them correctly. The code you show above is unfortunately broken in many places.

Comment: What is interesting is that obviously i know i have an issue with my code(hens why i asked), The code does show virtual directories, but does not distinguish between the types. an i do understand that every site has its root application, and every application has its root virtual directory, But trying to figure out without listing the main site virtual directory how to list them Separately. But dont get me wrong thanks for telling me my code is broken, it was a big help to the question(NOT). so unless you looking to help i think you should keep your rude comments to your self. Thanks though.

Comment: and i believe my issue is that virtual directories that are not applications use the path of the main site application, so thinking maybe if i do a if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(applicationPool). but not sure.